# 2014 Ford Focus won't start at all

Tags: ford, starting, fuel-system, focus, no-crank-no-start

My vehicle died on me suddenly on the road today. It  was stuttering for a few minutes hard prior to it dying. When I tried to jump it nothing happened at all, not a click, not a turn over, anything.

I'm aware that my model car had a recall last year for the canister purge valve & it causes excessive vacuuming & a faulty fuel pump but just haven't gotten it fixed yet. Could this be the issue? I'll also add that my mph & gas has be majorly decreasing & fluctuating the past week.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The purge valve wouldn't keep it from cranking. If jumping the vehicle isn't helping, you've got other issues.

Comment: When you turn the key on do you have lights on your dash? When it started stuttering did the dash lights flicker?

Comment: Yes i do have the lights on my dash & my regular car dings as well. The lights didn't exactly flicker but multiple came on at the same time. The battery & the engine. Now all of the lights are on.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the battery that came with the car from the factory, five years is beyond the expected end of life period.  Have the battery health checked at your local auto parts store (Autozone, etc.).